Replacing a nested if statement with a single if statement that has a logical && (AND) operator to achieve the same output
Below is a code that demonstrates a nested if statement for exam marks:
public class NestIfExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Asking the user to input their score
        System.out.print("Enter your score: ");
        int score = inputDevice.nextInt();

        // Outer if statement
        if (score >= 50) {
            System.out.println("You passed the exam!");

            // Inner if statement - only checked if the score is 50 or more
            if (score >= 80) {
                System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
        }
    }
}

How do I change this nested if statement to a single if statement that has the logical && (AND) operator and achieve the same output?
This is what I tried. I created a single if statement by joining two conditions and making them one condition, (score >= 80 && score >=50).
I'm not sure if it's correct. Please let me know.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Asking the user to input their score
    System.out.print("Enter your score: ");
    int score = inputDevice.nextInt();

    // Single if statement using logical AND (&&) operator
    if (score >= 80 && score >= 50) {
        System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
        System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
    } else if (score >= 50) {
        System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
    }
}


score >= 80 is enough for the first if, && score >= 50 is unnecessary.

Please stop shouting. There is no reason to put "single if statement" or "nested if statement" in all-caps.


Replacing a nested if statement with a single if statement that has a logical && (AND) operator to achieve the same output.

You can't do it with a single if statement, you will need at least two. You have three different cases.

a message if the score is >= 80
a second message if the score is >= 50 (which is checked if the score is below 80)
and a default message if the score is below 50.

But you don't need the bi-conditional in the first if statement. By checking the larger test requirement (>=80) first, you can do it as follows:
Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
// Asking the user to input their score
System.out.print("Enter your score: ");
int score = inputDevice.nextInt();


if (score >= 80) {
    System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
} else if (score >= 50) {
    System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
    System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
}

For entered scores of 80, 79, and 49, prints the following:
Enter your score: 80
Great job! You scored in the top range.
Enter your score: 79
You passed the exam!
Good effort, but there's room for improvement.
Enter your score: 49
Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.


Just be simple, man!
int score = ...;
final int scoreGood = 50;
final int scoreBest = 80;
 
if (score >= scoreGood)
    System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
else
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");

if (score >= scoreBest)
    System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
else if (score >= scoreGood)
    System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");


One of your conditions (score >= 80) is true when another of your conditions (score >= 50) is true. I would start by assigning those states to boolean(s). Like top and passing. And,
boolean top = score >= 80;
boolean passing = score >= 50;

Then your original outer else can be the first thing you check. Are they not passing or top (using DeMorgan's theorem) we can then use an && like,
if (!passing && !top) {
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
} else {
    System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
    if (top) {
        System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");
    }
}

You could omit some else(s) if you return early. Like,
boolean top = score >= 80, passing = score >= 50;
if (!passing && !top) {
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
    return;
} 
System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
if (top) {
    System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
    return;
}
System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");

Another approach would be taking the score and divide by 10. Then switch on the result. Building a very small jump table. Like,
String[] msgs = {
        "You passed the exam!\nGreat job! You scored in the top range.",
        "You passed the exam!\nGood effort, but there's room for improvement.",
        "Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time."
};
switch (score / 10) {
case 10: case 9: case 8: System.out.println(msgs[0]); break;
case 7: case 6: case 5: System.out.println(msgs[1]); break;
default: System.out.println(msgs[2]);
}


You are close, but you missed a print statement from the second condition:
// Asking the user to input their score
System.out.print("Enter your score: ");
int score = inputDevice.nextInt();

// Single if statement using logical AND (&&) operator
if (score >= 80 && score >= 50) {
    System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
    System.out.println("Great job! You scored in the top range.");
} else if (score >= 50) {  // implicit: score < 80 for this case
    System.out.println("You passed the exam!");
    // only change is next line
    System.out.println("Good effort, but there's room for improvement.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you did not pass. Try again next time.");
}

